# After PUT request object properties are shown as strings

Tags: php, laravel

Started working with Laravel 8 and little bit struggling with PUT request. Whenever I try to update(create actually new fields on update) a user with new properties they are shown as strings.

Here's my User migratiomn

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('type')->nullable();
        $table->string('profile')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here's my function from controller

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->update([
            'profile' => [
                'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
                'company_vat' => $request->input('company_vat'),
            ],
        ]);

        return response($user, 201);
    }
```

And here's how it looks from get request after doing put request. [image: request]

So the whole issue that they shouldn't be displayed as strings and actually I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to your model, it will save it as a json string in the database and json decode it on calls.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'profile' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for the last hour... Thank you!